# Swift - Prevent timer duplicating

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timer, swift3

I have a timer that runs in viewDidLoad

```
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10,
                                   target: self,
                                   selector: #selector(timerFired),
                                   userInfo: nil,
                                   repeats: true)
```

The timer works fine, the issue is because viewDidLoad is called multiple times, the timer is duplicated.

Is there any way to ensure that my timer is only ever running once?

Comment: viewDidLoad should only be called once, but anyway you should keep a reference to your timer and invalidate it.

Comment: I'm in a navigation view, whenever I go back to the view where the timer is fired it has little timer babies and there's loads running after a while

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to your timer so you can invalidate it when your viewController disappears. Otherwise it will just keep running and new timers will be spawned every time another viewController is created.

```
var timer:Timer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1,
                                 target: self,
                                 selector: #selector(timerFired),
                                 userInfo: nil,
                                 repeats: true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    if let timer = timer {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Depending on your navigation logic `viewWillDisappear` may get called multiple times before the view is deallocated, you'll have to decide the best way to handle this yourself.

Comment: If you're going to invalidate the timer in viewWillDisappear then it's probably better to create it in viewWillAppear. That way the timer will get created each time the view controller moves to the front. With the code in your answer the timer would get invalidated if you presented a modal, but a new timer would not be created when the modal was dismissed. Also it's probably safer to make the timer a normal optional and use `timer?.invalidate()`. That way if the timer is nil the invalidate is simply skipped instead of crashing the program.

Comment: `if let timer = timer {timer.invalidate()}` can be expressed much more compactly as `timer?.invalidate()`.

Comment: When will a call to `viewWillAppear` **ever** fail to be balanced by a call to `viewWillDisappear`, except when the app is terminated without closing the window?

Comment: OK I was wrong about that, I was thinking of interactive transitions. I'm only answering the question about why the timer never disappeared, if you want to give a code sample for every use case, go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

The viewDidLoad method is only called once in the lifetime of your view controller.

If you have multiple timers running then you probably have multiple instances of your view controller. Otherwise you would likely crash when you popped your view controller off the navigation stack and your timer tried to call it again.

You need to balance things you create in viewDidLoad by freeing them.

### EDIT:

Normally you balance things you create in viewDidLoad by putting cleanup code in a `deinit` method. However, it looks like a running timer keeps a strong reference to it's target. Thus if your view controller is the target of a running timer then it's deinit method won't be called.

I would suggest creating your timer in viewWillAppear and invalidating it in viewWillDisappear:

```
weak var timer: Timer?



override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0,
    target: self,
    selector: #selector(timerFired(timer:)), 
    userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
  timer?.invalidate()
}
```

### EDIT #2:

Alternately, you could use the new-to-iOS 10 version of scheduledTimer() that takes a **block** rather than a target/selector. **FINALLY** Apple created this function. it's about d*amned time!

```
weak var timer: Timer?


override func viewDidLoad() {

  super.viewDidLoad()
  timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0,
    repeats: true) {
    [weak self] timer in
    //Your timer code here
}


deinit {
  timer?.invalidate()
}
```

Comment: `deinit` won't be called if the timer is still valid, it has to be in viewWillDisappear or similar.

Comment: Oh, you're right. A running timer keeps a strong reference to it's target. Time to edit my answer.

Comment: To go along with what @DuncanC said about strong references to timers, Apple's Timer documentation states "that run loops maintain strong references to their timers, so you don’t have to maintain your own strong reference to a timer after you have added it to a run loop." I'd suggest never keeping a strong reference to timers unless it's neccessary.